# awk replace all occurrences of a string globally

Tags: string, bash, awk, replace

I have a bash script that substitutes strings in another file:

```
...
# make MC input script
sig=2.6
awk -v sig="$sig" '{
        sub(/XSIGX/, sig);
        print;  

}' input.txt > output.txt
```

When I run this on `input.txt` I get the following as `output.txt` (notice replacements as "2.6" but the lack thereof in the `cat` line):

```
...
echo "hi" >> /work/d/dfranz/o2_modeling/simulated_densities_2.6.txt

cat /work/d/dfranz/o2_modeling/simulated_densities_2.6.txt | sort -nk1 > /work/d/dfranz/o2_modeling/simulated_rho_sorted_XSIGX.txt  # <--- This XSIGX was not replaced but the first occurrence in this line was
rm /work/d/dfranz/o2_modeling/simulated_densities_2.6.txt
```

Comment: AFAIK sub replaces one, gsub replaces them all. Did you try gsub?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I didn't know about gsub. Thank you kindly -- if you post a quick answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In AWK function `sub` replaces one/first instance. If you replace `sub` with `gsub` should replace all instances. Hence this should work ok:

```
sig=2.6
awk -v sig="$sig" '{
        gsub(/XSIGX/, sig);
        print;  

}' input.txt > output.txt
```